# Create a HTML form that submits from the fillers mail address to my email address

Tags: php, html, email

I have a HTML form on my site that submits using a very simple PHP script. As the script is written now I receive the form in my email address, the email that i receive has both the To and From fields as my email address. I.E if person1@email.com fills in the form I receive an email that says

```
From : my_email@email.com
To   : my_email@email.com
```

I would like to change the script so that the From is the persons email address that filled in the form. I.E the mail I receive should be:

```
From : person1@email.com
To   : my_email@email.com
```

This way I will be able to set up a automated reply on the mail account so that as a person fills in the form they will receive a welcome mail from my account.

Below is the HTML form code that I use:

```
<form action="../php/submit-candidate-form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
       <p>1) What is your name?</p>
            <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>

       <p>2) What is your E-Mail address?</p>
            <input class="input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>


    <button class="main-button icon-button">Submit form</button>
```

And this is the simple php script that I use:

```
<?php
$subject = 'Email Subject line.';

$emailadd = 'my_email@email.com';

$url = 'http://www.example.com/thankyou';

$req = '0';

$text = "You have recieved the following message from the form:\n\n"; 
$space = ' ';
$line = '
';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($req == '1') {
        if ($value == '') {
            echo "$key is empty";
            die;
        }
    }
    $j = strlen($key);
    if ($j >= 20) {
        echo "Name of form element $key cannot be longer than 20 characters";
        die;
    }
    $j = 20 - $j;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $j; $i++) {
        $space .= ' ';
    }
    $value = str_replace('\n', "$line", $value);
    $conc = "{$key}:$space{$value}$line";
    $text .= $conc;
    $space = ' ';
}
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: In this code I dont see how `$req` would ever `== '1'`

Comment: _“I would like to change the script so that the From is the persons email address that filled in the form”_ - no, you don’t want that. That would put the mail at a massively increased risk of being classified as _spam_ - simply because your server would be sending out mails for completely arbitrary domains, that it is not really marked as an “allowed” sender for.

Comment: I dont know why you are using a loop to collect the 2 statically named fields from the form? Could you simply use `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['email']` and make the code a lot easier to read and maintain

Comment: To expand on @04FS comment. Most hosts will not allow email to be sent from your domain unless it is sent using an FromAddress that is registered on/to that domain.

Comment: You might like to use a `ReplyTo` as the other persons email address. That would work

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$emailadd.'');
```

to

```
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$_POST['email'].'');
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see, you are using same variable in place of "To" and "From". If you want two different emails so you have to change them like this:

```
$from_email = "person1@email.com";
mail($emailadd, $subject, $text, 'From: '.$from_email.'');
```

Here, you can add the email you want in $from_email.